# How do I echo the link and it's text from a scraped page with PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, hyperlink, echo

So I am in the need of line of code that echos a link so that the $text is the text of the link and the $href is the href value.

Comment: The question really doesn't open too well. Can you tell us more?

Comment: your comment makes no sense "open too well" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<a href='$href'>$text</a><br />\n";
```