# how to put a variable inside a variable value PHP

Tags: php, variables

So I want to put a variable value in this link where "90" is and I'm not sure how to do it. 
Does anyone know how to do this?  Sorry for the stupid question I'm relatively new to programming with PHP.

```
$url = "http://junna.com/mamba90nina";
```

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm relatively new to programming with PHP" --- if you are, why don't you start learning from very basics?

Comment: `preg_replace` is what you might be looking for. If your "new to PHP` then regex will be very complicated for you

Comment: Isn't this pretty much like [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006445/how-do-i-echo-the-link-and-its-text-from-a-scraped-page-with-php) on outputting variables within some text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do so by creating the variable (`$value` as I've done below) and then concatenating the `$url` string using `.`

```
$value = '90';
$url = "http://junna.com/mamba" . $value . "nina";
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is scrape this url but when I try it I get this error:

Comment: cURL error number:6
cURL error:Couldn't resolve host

Comment: @michaelrouse You say nothing about `cURL` or scraping in this post ...

Comment: I know I said that because I was wondering if you knew how to fix this.

Comment: For some reason it's really picky.

Comment: Never mind I got it! For some reason it only works for double quoted variable values.  Thanks though!